# How to create popup window inside in pdf also place textbox fields in this pdf using itextsharp

Tags: javascript, pdf, itext

We have crating pdf dynamically with the help of itextsharp.Now I want to show popup window on button click with the help of JavaScript fuction.How we can create this window in pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `window.open()` method to create a popup in javascript, including a link in the url parameter, along with the name and any optional parameters.

```
<button class="popup" onclick="createPopup()"/>

function createPopup(url, name) {
  let popup = open(url, name, 'width=500,height=500')
  popup.focus();
}
```

You can then use `window.opener()` to return values from the popup to the parent.

Hope this helps.